# Query metadata from HIVE using MySQL as metastore

Tags: mysql, hive, odbc, metadata, hiveql

I am looking for a way to query the metadata of my HIVE data with a HiveQL command.

I configured a MySQL metastore, but it is necessary to query the metadata via HIVE command because then I want to access the data with ODBC connection to the HIVE system.

Comment: _" it is necessary to query the metadata via HIVE command because then I want to access the data with ODBC connection"_ > what does that mean? You are not happy with standard Hive commands such as `show tables in <DB>`, `describe table <DB.TBL>`, `show partitions  <DB.TBL>`,  `show create table  <DB.TBL>` ?

Answer (score 1):

To see them from Hive, you must use the commands to display the DDL. You'll probably need to parse it.

Database metadata:

```
describe database extended <db_name>
```

To see table and columns metadata:

```
describe formatted <db_name>.<table_name>
```

Another option is to directly connect to the matastore database, but you'll be outside Hive.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it currently using Hive JDBC StorageHandler: https://github.com/qubole/Hive-JDBC-Storage-Handler

Example of table creation from their page:

```
DROP TABLE HiveTable;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE HiveTable(
  id INT,
  id_double DOUBLE,
  names STRING,
  test INT
)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storagehandler.JdbcStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "mapred.jdbc.driver.class"="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
  "mapred.jdbc.url"="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rstore",
  "mapred.jdbc.username"="root",
  "mapred.jdbc.input.table.name"="JDBCTable",
  "mapred.jdbc.output.table.name"="JDBCTable",
  "mapred.jdbc.password"="",
  "mapred.jdbc.hive.lazy.split"= "false"
);
```

I tested, it works fine with MySQL. And FilterPushDown  also works.

Answer (score 0):

There are already a bunch of tables in the SYS db and the INFORMATION_SCHEMA db which maps to the tables in the RDBMS.
Check this file:
https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/1e3e07c87e71dc16f05ad269b250d65ad7c02232/metastore/scripts/upgrade/hive/hive-schema-4.0.0-alpha-2.hive.sql

If the table isn't there you can create hive tables pointing to mysql, the same way it is done in this file.
eg.
https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/1e3e07c87e71dc16f05ad269b250d65ad7c02232/metastore/scripts/upgrade/hive/hive-schema-4.0.0-alpha-2.hive.sql#L1520-L1546